# Hover event isn't working with a div following the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div called `hoverZone`, and another called `followMouse`. `The followMouse`div, as the name suggests is always following the mouse, the problem is that in my css I have this rule that never gets applied:

```
.hoverZone:hover ~ .followMouse {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #fff;
}
```

Any ideas on how to bypass this problem?

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);

function move(e){
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY);
     
    var follower = document.querySelector(".followMouse");
    follower.style.left = mouseX + "px";
    follower.style.top = mouseY + "px";
}
```

```css
.hoverZone {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
}

.hoverZone:hover ~ .followMouse {
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #fff;
}

.followMouse{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverZone"></div>
<div class="followMouse"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.followMouse` has `position:static;` by default so change `top`, `left` and etc doesn't have any effect on element. Give `position: absolute;` to `.followMouse` will fix your problem.

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);

function move(e){
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY);
     
    var follower = document.querySelector(".followMouse");
    follower.style.left = mouseX + "px";
    follower.style.top = mouseY + "px";
}
```

```css
.hoverZone {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
}

.hoverZone:hover ~ .followMouse {
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #000;
}

.followMouse{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: orange;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverZone"></div>
<div class="followMouse"></div>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, I've forgotten to put that on my code above, but `followMouse`'s position is fixed (`position: fixed;`), but why must it be absolute?

Comment: doesn't matter, u can give `postion:fixed`.

Comment: You can give the followMouse class css rule `pointer-events: none` to stop it from stealing the event from hoverZone

Comment: @OmriLuzon Thank you, that's it!

Comment: @Safirah I change the `position` to `fixed` and then for removing `event-pointer` from `.followMouse ` u can use Omir's comment.